# What is the process of an if-statement when evaluating an object for a specific property directly?

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, search

I am fairly new to programming and have come across this problem when exploring objects. It appears that an if-statement can search for a property inside of an object without the use of hasOwnProperty() or the keyword 'in' or anything else for that matter. You can just type something like:

```
if (object.property) {code here};
```

I searched the web but no content on why this is possible. Except some shallow discussions on truthy or falsy concepts. Which almost helped but were to shallow. Below is the sample code I used to discover this problem

```
var obj = {
    prop1: {
        propa: "x",
        propb: ["b", "q", "y"],
        prop3: "y",
        prop4: "zz"
    }
},
    output = document.getElementById("output");
if (obj.prop1) {
    output.innerHTML = "The propery exist.";  //The property exist shows. 
} else {
    output.innerHTML = "The property does not exist.";
}
```

So the question is What is the process that a Javascript if-statement performs to return a boolean answer from a statement such as **if (object.property) {}**?

Comment: Yes, truthiness and falsyness are exactly what is applied here. The value in the `if` condition is cast to a boolean, like with `!!x` or `Boolean(x)`, and that's what decides the control flow. Accessing a non-existing property on an object yields the value `undefined`, which is one of the falsy values - treated like `false` in the condition.

Comment: Thank you very much Bergi, but does that mean when you put an expression such as if (object.property) {}. It 1) navigates to the object 2)searches the properties in the object for that specific property by name in the object. 3) evaluates to true if found false if not found

Comment: No, it evaluates to the value of the property if found or `undefined` if not found. Just like any property access does. Then, in a fourth step, which happens because the value is used in an `if` condition where a boolean is expected, the value is cast to a boolean.

Comment: If it helps: it doesn't evaluate different than `var value = obj..prop1; if (val) { … } else { … }`

Comment: Yes, it  did help. If I were to have a value that evaluated to false such as NaN in prop1 instead of an object which evaluates to true. I could have seen it sooner it appears. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all programming languages, JavaScript expects an expression evaluating to a boolean value between the braces in `if (expr)`. Now, when the expression does not evaluate to a boolean value, JavaScript uses what is known as coercion to convert the value. That is, it implictly runs `if(Boolean(object.property)) {}` when evaluating `if (object.property) {}`.

The outcome of this operation depends on the value of `object.property` and you may consult this table for how this works:

https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Or read the documentation on truthiness semantics from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).

Note however the difference between your discovery and checking whether a property exists:

```
const object = { property: false };
if (object.property) {
    console.log("No go. The value evaluates to false.")
} 

if ("property" in object) {
    console.log("Yes. The property exists.");
}
```